# query with overlength keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field with fixed 12-characters length. With keywords have less than 12 characters, I use this command to query:

```
SELECT description
FROM sometable
WHERE description LIKE '%keywords%'
```

In this column, how could I find `stackoverflow` with both 2 keywords `stackoverflowssss` or `ssssstackoverflow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT description
FROM sometable
WHERE description LIKE '%keyword%'
OR 'keyword' LIKE CONCAT('%',description,'%')
```

... a real performance killer though!

Answer (score 0):

Add a % between every space. Like:

```
WHERE description LIKE '%".str_replace(' ', '%', $keywords)."%'
```